# Laravel Updating System

Tags: git, laravel-5, updating

The application is written on Laravel 5.0. Now I would like to "install" my web application on several environments (means several servers). But always copying the changed files seems too costly for me.  I'd like to only have to trigger maybe a script, and all applications on all servers will be updated (except the config files).

Maybe something like that is possible with **git**?

Comment: Well what you are looking for is kind of a build server I guess. `git` is not a build server at all. So now, git is applicable for this. But you can have the both, `git` and a build server work together.

Comment: @ckruczek Thank you for answer! Can you be more specific or do you have an article/link for more information.

Comment: Well you could use `git` as it was for its purpose :D And jenkis as a build server. On jenkins you definitly could add some after build hooks I guess.

Comment: Perfect. So is git it the most common solution for an updating system? On the other hand, i could write an updating system on my own.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/envoy

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can surely do it using git but it will only fetch your code only not server configuration.
For the laravel installation and your coding: Just make a git repository and upload your code over there and just pull the code from git remote command.

**But**, It will not auto-configure your server. Like installing composer, mcrypt, lamp stack and so on. That you will need to configure.

Comment: Of course. Server configuration need another solution (manually or scriptbased). But I don't know what is the most used solution for updating web applications. For example a long time ago I used Joomla 3.x. And in the backend they always informed you as soon new updatees were found. You could then just trigger the update button and your Joomla version will be updated to the newest one.